# Constructor for buttons

Tags: java, button, parameters, constructor

I have a text file that contains something like:

```
parameter 1 = true    
parameter 2 = true    
parameter 3 = false
```

and this goes on for over 90 parameters. I am creating a program that will read from this file and create buttons that will have different states depending if the parameter is set to true or false, and also alternate between these states.

My question is: To make this buttons, is there a way to create a constructor to be called that can create the buttons for me or do i have to copy and paste everything, one at a time? As I am relatively new to programming, I've been looking for days but I was never able to make it.

PS: I don't need the code for the states of the buttons, I just need to know if there is a simpler and quice, and if there is, how do I do it.

Comment: `"To make this buttons, is there a way to create a constructor to be called that can create the buttons for me or do i have to copy and paste everything, one at a time?"` -- Not sure what you're asking here, but the key to smart programming is to keep things simple and to avoid repeating yourself. Perhaps you should start coding and see what you can come up with, since I have a feeling that once you get your hands wet, you'll have a better idea of the real problems that you must deal with.

Comment: You probably want to use a loop.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you don't need the names from the text file (parameter 1, etc), one possible solution is to try going through the text file and save each value to a boolean array. Then you can do something like this:

```
List<MyButton> buttons = new ArrayList<MyButton>();
for (int i = 0; i < buttonValues.length; i++) { //buttonValues is the array of booleans
    buttons.add(new MyButton(buttonValues[i]);
}
```

Where `MyButton` is a class you make that has a constructor that takes a boolean value to indicate its state.

You don't even need to save the values in an array, you could skip straight to making the buttons as you read the file. You would change it to a while loop with the condition along the lines of `myFileReader.hasNext()` and pass the constructor the boolean value as you read it. You could also easily read the name of the parameter here as well, if you want to keep track of it. Just update `MyButton`'s constructor to take the name.

Answer (score 0):

You can read line by line and create a buttons in runtime  for each line :

```
    public Frame() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("1.txt"))) {
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            // read line by line
            String[] paramAndValue = new String[2];
            // split key/value
            paramAndValue = line.split(" = ");
            // add a Jbutton with the key as name
            JButton button = new JButton(paramAndValue[0]);
            // and the value as the state 
            button.setEnabled(Boolean.parseBoolean(paramAndValue[1]));
            this.add(button);
        }
    }
}
```